# chat - How to manage lookup for new incoming messages to a server?

Tags: android, sqlite, chat, google-cloud-messaging

i'm implementing a chat application with a lightweight architecture.

I'm using Google Cloud Messaging to handle notification from server to Android client (new message incoming, new friendship request,...).

I have a ListView of people that an user X can talk with. For performance and robustness reasons is expensive make a "new messages lookup" when I open one conversation with a user Y. Normally all the latest messages are stored in the SQLite DB and they are available immediatly. The problem is to manage new messages incoming...

So what is the best architecture?

- push notification to the android client when new message is arrived -> lookup immediatly on the server to get all new messages from user Y.
- but what should i do if the notification does not arrive? Do I need a service that makes lookup at a certain moment during the activity chat lifecycle? For example when every time when the chat activity goes onPause()?
- Any performance hint to store efficently messages into the SQLite db and to make faster lookups from the the server db?

Comment: @helldron-just tried your code what u have tried for better understanding.

Comment: Do you have discovered some critical problem in my process? Essentially I think that there are performance problem (too much record to load during user interaction when he open an activty) and robustness (not sure that push notifications will arrive)